# How do I map multiple HTTP parameters to a JSON array using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda that takes a list of skus,

```
{ "skus" : [
    "sku1", 
    "sku2"
    ] 
}
```

I want to invoke it from HTTP requests to either

```
/inventory/sku1,sku2
```

or

```
/inventory?sku=sku1&sku=sku2
```

How can I achieve that mapping in API Gateway?

Comment: Look at example here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html under header "Param Mapping Template Example".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any help there parsing /inventory/sku1,sku2 into a list to iterate over, and, at least in the Method Test UI, I don't seem to be able to repeat a query string parameter

Comment: Is it ok for you to make a GET request like `/?skus=[1,2,3,4]` ? In this case you can just map one param.

Comment: That doesn't look ideal, but I think I have discovered a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String::split for the path-based approach.

```
#set($skus = $input.params('skus').split(","))
{
  "skus": [ 
     #foreach($sku in $skus)
      "$sku"
     #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
     #end
  ]
}
```